# How can I cast a string into a boolean in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

In MSSQL query there is the following line, resulted in a boolean

```
   IS_IDENTITY = COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('#attributes.table#'), 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity')
```

in MYsql, I can only use subquery, but it ends in a string.

```
(SELECT COLUMN_NAME INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINTS_NAME = "PRIMARY") AS RESULT
```

How can I cast the "RESULT" into a boolean from a string in a mysql query?

Thanks.

Comment: Ifnull() function?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a "real" boolean type. Boolean expressions return either `0` or `1` (or `NULL`). What is the string you get? And what is your actual query? What you have posted won't run (in MySQL).

Comment: ,, besides what @PaulSpiegel said MSSQL `IDENTITY` in MySQL this is `AUTO_INCREMENT` not only `PRIMARY KEY.`, also as you can make a PRIMARY KEY **without** a AUTO_INCREMENT..

Answer (score 0):

The [CASE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) could be what you are looking for, but this is just a guess. Could you try to reformulate your question so it gets a bit more understandable what you are doing and what your use case is?

Comment: Thank you.  In MSSQL there is 'is_identity" boolean flag, I need to also able to generate this flag in Mysql.  Because my current CF code was originally written for MSSQL, now I need it to work with  Mysql.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have a function like SQL Server's `COLUMNPROPERTY`, but you can create your own:

```
delimiter $$
create function f_column_property( 
in_db varchar(64), 
in_table varchar(64), 
in_column varchar(64),
in_constraint_name  varchar(64)
)
returns boolean
begin

declare v_cnt int;

select count(*) into v_cnt
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
where TABLE_SCHEMA=in_db and TABLE_NAME=in_table and COLUMN_NAME=in_column 
  and CONSTRAINT_NAME=in_constraint_name;

if (v_cnt>0) then 
  return true;
else 
  return false;
end if;

end
$$
```

And then use it in a query:

```
select f_column_property('mydb', 'mytable', 'mycolumn', 'PRIMARY') as 'is_identity'
```

See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Since I never created a function before, can you tell me where to place these code?  I am an very old Cold Fusion guy.  :-)

Comment: You can paste it into the MySQL command line. Basically creating a function is the same as any other query you pass to the database. In command line the default delimiter (=string that tells when the command ends) is the semicolon, but as routines (functions/stored procedures) use semicolon internally, you have to change the delimiter before the function creation. Added a link to documentation.

Comment: Without the full code and the error message it is impossible to help. Also, it's unclear what you mean by 'I dropped the in_column variable, because it is already in the "select"' as you do need to specify the column you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Since my query is..   
SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE, 
f_column_property('fbel', '#attributes.table#', 'PRIMARY') as 'is_identity'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
I took out "in_column" variable from your code.  I suspect that I did it wrong.  Please advise.

Comment: Let me explain a little further.  The query is to result in all the columns of a table, and set is_identity flag if it is a primary key.   Please advise.  It is the last hurdle now.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Aha, I got it to work,  I inserted "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME" in place of "in-column".  It works perfectly now.  Thank you so much for your kindness.  73 year old CF programmer.

Comment: Unless you're reusing this fn all over the place, it might be more sensible just to use the expression: `EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mydb' AND TABLE_NAME='mytable' AND COLUMN_NAME='mycolumn' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='PRIMARY')`.

Taking a COUNT(*) and then comparing it to 0 is just pointless:  that's what `EXISTS()` is for!

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it to tinyINT(1). This is equivalent to boolean.